# how to add a # to a var

Tags: jquery

Hi h have some code which brings back the class name of a link

```
var activeTab = $(this).attr("class");
```

so lets say the above brings back a value of 'one'

i need to append this to be #one for the below code

```
var activeTab = $(this).attr("class"); 
          $(activeTab).stop(true, false).animate({ height: "200px" });
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use + operator for string concatenation like this:

```
$('#' + activeTab)
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple in Javascript:

```
var_name = '#' + var_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use + for string concatenation:

```
$('#' + activeTab)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var activeTab = $(this).attr("class"); 
activeTab = '#' + activeTab;
$(activeTab).stop(true, false).animate({ height: "200px" });
```

Comment: I'm being explicit in my answer. Second like is not necessarily needed in the real code, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

$('#' + activeTab) ....

?!

```
var activeTab = $(this).attr("class"); 
$("#" + activeTab).stop(true, false).animate({ height: "200px" });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var activeTab = "#" + $(this).attr("class"); 
$(activeTab).stop(true, false).animate({ height: "200px" });
```

I think that's what you want to do.